# Cant find navbar element in Selenium Webdriver for Heroku

Tags: selenium, webdriver

So we're using Heroku for a student project and we are supposed to use Selenium to test the product throughout the course, however I am not able to locate any of the elements inside the navbar. This given that we decide to show the navbar etc as a precondition.

I could locate it before we introduced the toggle thingy if i am not mistaken.

https://c3-solutions-staging.herokuapp.com/
I was not able to locate any of the elements inside the navbar, including the navbar itself with the  find element function, although i tried xpath, css, id etc. What i want to do is to either click the Enhetsöversikt or select the input type field so that i can search. Been bugging me out for a few hours by now : )            We're using Javascript with Vue as framework so that might be an issue? Has been an interesting experience lately <:

Comment: Which `elements inside the navbar`?

Comment: Instead of a comment update the main question with all those information.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='Enhetsöversikt']").click() Should simply click that element if it is visible. #searchbar > input[type=text] could be a css selector for the search one.

Comment: Which prog lang are you using? Your code trials?